# iOS - Integrating credit card payments

Tags: ios, credit-card, in-app

I'm aware that we can integrate in-app purchases with storekit. but i want to integrate payments using credit card. will apple allow to integrate such libraries? Are there any such libraries available where users can use their credit card for payment of products with in my app?

Comment: As long as the product is not a virtual good, you are good to go with whatever payment solution. If, for example, you plan to sell physical goods like a book or a CD or a big pack of douche-bags, using PayPal or similar services is totally fine.

Comment: @Satyam: have you integrated credit card payments in ios app? I also want to do same? can u please help me on this?

Comment: @Bhargavi: No, I didn't integrate. Apple suggests to go with inapp purchases. As answered in below, you can use the library mentioned if needed. "http://stripe.com"

Comment: apple would suggest inappp purchase of course.i would also not say no to  30 % revenue provision for no effort =)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Depending on what users are purchasing*, you should be just fine accepting payments in your app. Instead of trying to incorporate some type of payment library into the app I would recommend using a payment API that offloads the work. Take a look at http://stripe.com/ for an example of an excellent payment system designed for ease of integration. Their API reference even [mentions integration with iPhone apps](https://stripe.com/docs/api#tokens).

*If you are trying to sell features or services of the app itself you will almost definitely be running afoul of Apple's guidelines, but based on the fact that you said "products" I am assuming this is not the case. In fact, while you must use the in-app purchase system for "content, functionality, or services in an app" you are specifically forbidden from using it for "physical goods or goods and services used outside of the application" (item 11.3 of Apple's App Store Review Guidelines).

Comment: This is blatantly false. The only way you can make a payment through an iOS app is through an official In App Purchase.

Comment: @Peter Are you telling me you've never used Amazon's app? Or FAB's? Or any number of other apps that allow you to purchase products through an app? Apple only regulates selling additional features and services related to the app - like magazine subscriptions or additional game levels.

Comment: Take a look at the question again: "users can use their credit card for payment of **products *with in* my app**."

Comment: @Peter I would take that as meaning purchases occurring within the app, not necessarily purchases that will be used within the app, but you could be right so I added some additional clarification to my post.

Comment: @Peter  You should probably review the difference between in-app purchases (which deliver digital products) and in-app billing which allows for selling products.  Please refrain from naively accusing someone of being blatantly false without knowing all of the facts

Comment: Stripe seems like a decent tool. Their support is terrible.

Comment: In 2k18 it's `3.1.5 Goods and Services Outside of the App`

Answer (score 6):

Apple **does** allow not Apple's IAP in-app payments for goods not consumed in the phone (Digital content) as stated above.
See this example of an approved app that use external library for accepting credit cards in their app:
**[iStash](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/istash-cards/id486722915?mt=8)**

In my opinion Stripe is good solution but not the ideal for in-app as it is a web based solution and focuses on web experience.

If you want a true mobile in-app experience I suggest you check out PayPal library or my company, [ZooZ](http://zooz.com), which accepts both PayPal and Credit Cards in one integration.

Comment: I can't understand your "how it works" on your website. The image is a bit confusing :)

Comment: You are right, it is not very clear, soon we will replace it with a Video :)

Comment: @RonenMorecki Does your service allow storing of the preferred payment option for the user, so that one doesn't need to enter it every time? Think of Uber where you just click the Confirm button and payment is done without the need of entering payment details.

Comment: @Ska Yes we do, a lot has changed since this post above, but yes we do support storing the payment method

Comment: @RonenMorecki Off topic, but is it possible to have a marketplace type apps, where different merchants specify their preferred payout gateway, buyers their preferred payment method. And when a buyer buys from merchant, the money goes directly from the buyer's method into merchant's account, without the main app getting anything? The merchants would be paying subscription to be on the platform.

Comment: Yes this is possible
some platforms support such model like the one I founded - Zooz
or others like Spreedly

Answer (score 2):

working project can be find [here](https://github.com/collision/stripe-ios) on github stripe example.

Answer (score 1):

As an iOS dev you'd best have a good read through [this](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html). Specifically pertinent to you is section 11.2:

> **11.2** Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be rejected

They want the profit, and they get their cut if you use the IAP API. Hope that clears up any issues.

**EDIT:** I am assuming based on the wording of your question that the payment will unlock something transitory in the app. IAP are only appropriate when purchasing something digital. *If* what you are selling is physically tenable, then you shouldn't, and in fact are not allowed, to use the IAP API. In that case, something along the lines of [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs) or a web-based version of [Paypal's](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks) API would work.

Answer (score 0):

In support of [David's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8762161/3962892) answer, I would like to add that, using a payment API to accept payments for products/donation through your app would be ideal.

Apple Pay is now available (as of today) on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus, and active only in US.

But if you still want to add support in your app for devices that cannot use Apple Pay, [Authorize.Net](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-ios) now has an iOS SDK which you can use to integrate and enable credit card payments.