# iOS enterprise app store, include a way to accept credit card payments

Tags: ios, store, enterprise

When developing an app for the iOS enterprise app store can you include a way to accept credit card payments?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS - Integrating credit card payments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762096/ios-integrating-credit-card-payments)

Comment: It's an enterprise app. Apple never reviews or approves it, right? So you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what users are purchasing*, you should be just fine accepting payments in your app. Instead of trying to incorporate some type of payment library into the app I would recommend using a payment API that offloads the work. Take a look at http://stripe.com/ for an example of an excellent payment system designed for ease of integration. Their API reference even mentions integration with iPhone apps.

*If you are trying to sell features or services of the app itself you will almost definitely be running afoul of Apple's guidelines, but based on the fact that you said "products" I am assuming this is not the case. In fact, while you must use the in-app purchase system for "content, functionality, or services in an app" you are specifically forbidden from using it for "physical goods or goods and services used outside of the application" (item 11.3 of Apple's App Store Review Guidelines).

Answer (score 0):

You can use any technologies that that you would use in a regular app.  PayPal, Square Pay, etc.

Comment: are you sure? Because on  http://learnct.3m.com/production/cninv000000000003908/content.pdf it shows that you cannot.